# Run an UIActivityIndicatorView while the main thread is busy

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

is there a way to display the animated spinning wheel while the main thread does a lengthy operation? The animation is handled by the same thread that created the UIActivityIndicatorView, right? If so, can views that belong to several threads sit in the same view hierarchy?

All else failing, I don't mind moving a lengthy operation itself into a background thread, but then I'd have to freeze the UI somehow while it's running. That I'm not sure how to do.

EDIT: "lengthy" is around 2 sec on a 1st-gen device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to start the animation at least one iteration through the run loop before running the lengthy operation.  For example:

```
[activity startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(lengthyOperation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

You don't have to use the `performSelector` method, just some way to set the method to run *later* so the activity indicator has a chance to start animating before you get busy.

Comment: Heck, I was close :) Tried performSelectorOnMainThread, but it seems like delay was the key.

Comment: @Seva Running lengthy operations on the main thread is generally a bad idea.

Comment: What Giao says is true.  However, if you need the application to pause while it's happening, it doesn't seem like a TERRIBLE idea.  A better solution, however, might be to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] and endIgnoringInteractionEvents when you're done.

Comment: I have to agree with Giao; the main thread/run loop should *never* be stalled--the OS will terminate an application that has its main thread stalled for too long.

Comment: yes but isn't it the case that the main thread isn't being 'stalled' here? the main thread is running a lengthy operation which isn't the same as being stalled (or am i mistaken?). @ed Marty does this force the UIActivityIndicator onto a background thread (i read somewhere that the OS forces the activity indicator onto the main thread no matter what you specify - which, I presume was the original problem here...).

Comment: "the main thread/run loop should never be stalled": what about core data -- if I have a long running query that returns thousands of objects, it may take a couple seconds.  And, from what I understand, if I want to use the core data objects on the main thread I have to run the query on the main thread.  This seems to be the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The right answer is definitely to move the lengthly operation to a background thread and have it communicate to the main thread when it's done.  If you don't know how to do this, read on `NSOperationQueue` and `NSInvocationOperation`.  Your app and your users will thank you for the minimal time it will take to learn.